# Data-event-click only called once, why?

Tags: dashing, batman.js

I am making a custom widget in Shopify Dashing  with the following code:

```
<div class="main">
  <div id="bar">
     <a href="Info" data-event-click="toggleDetails">Info</a>
     </div>
  <div id="summary" data-bind="summary"></div>
  <div id="info" data-bind="info"></div>

  <h2 data-bind="more"></h3>
</div>
```

When the "Info"  tag is clicked it is supposed to toggle the views shown in the widget. This works fine the first time it is clicked and the function toggleDetails is called as expected. When it is clicked a second or third time however nothing happens, the function is never called.

Why is this? I really don't understand.

This is my coffescript class:

```
  1 class Dashing.Toggle extends Dashing.Widget
  2 
  3   ready: ->
  4     # This is fired when the widget is done being rendered
  5     #@showDetails = false
  6     @showSummary = true
  7     @initiateView()
  8 
  9   onData: (data) ->
 10     # Handle incoming data
 11     # You can access the html node of this widget with `@node`
 12     # Example: $(@node).fadeOut().fadeIn() will make the node flash each time data comes in.
 13 
 14 
 15   @accessor 'toggleDetails', ->
 16     @switchView()
 17     console.log "toggling 1"
 18 
 19   initiateView: ->
 20     @summaryView().show()
 21     @infoView().hide()
 22 
 23   switchView: ->
 24     console.log "Switching"
 25     if @showSummary
 26       @summaryView().fadeOut @animationLength()
 27       @infoView().fadeIn @animationLength()
 28       @showSummary = false
 29     else
 30       @infoView().fadeOut @animationLength()
 31       @summaryView().fadeIn @animationLength()
 32       @showSummary = true
 33 
 34   summaryView: ->
 35     console.log "getting summary view"
 36     $(@node).find("#summary")
 37 
 38   infoView: ->
 39     console.log "getting info view"
 40     $(@node).find("#info")
 41 
 42   animationLength: ->
 43     1000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I just solved it myself :P I still don't know why but changing form calling the @accessor method toggleDetails to switchView worked wonders. Does anyone know why?

Comment: In batman.js, `@accessor` is for declaring properties. Functions (including event handlers) should be instance functions, like `switchView` in the example above.

Accessor values are cached unless their dependencies changed. For this reason, the click handler worked _once_. The accessor was evaluated the first time, but wasn't evaluated a second time. Instead, the cached value (whatever `console.log` returns ...) was returned.